# Zend Framework: MySQL insertion error of timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, insertion

I have multiple insertion into the db from a form. Code is given below:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
               $UserID=$_POST['UserID'];
               $StartTime=$_POST['StartTime'];
               $StartDate=$_POST['StartDate'];
               $EndTime=$_POST['EndTime'];
               $EndDate=$_POST['EndDate'];
               $TimeWorked=$_POST['TimeWorked'];
               $i=0;
               foreach( $UserID as $key => $n ) 
               {
                   $UID=$UserID[$key];
                   $TW=$TimeWorked[$key];
                   $Stime =strtotime("{$StartTime[$key]} {$StartDate[$key]}");
                   $Etime = strtotime("{$EndTime[$key]} {$EndDate[$key]}");
                   echo $i."-".$n."::user Id".$UID.."//Stime:".$Stime."//Etime:".$Etime."<br/>";

                   $tasks = new Timesheets_Table_Tasks();

                   $tasks->createRow()
                   ->setFromArray(array
                       (
                           'Date'=>time(),
                           'UserID'=>$UID,
                           'Time'=>$TW,
                           'StartTime'=>$Stime,
                           'EndTime'=>$Etime

                       ))
                       ->save();
                   $i++;

               }
}
```

Everything is inserted into the database except StartTime & EndTime. I can display the values using this line

```
'echo $i."-".$n."::user Id".$UID.."//Stime:".$Stime."//Etime:".$Etime."<br/>";'
```

(just before the insertion). But nothing is inserted in the database.

The example value of StartTime & EndTime is 1427693580(timestamp).

**Mysql Structure:**

- Type: int(11)
- Null:Yes
- Default: NULL.

I am not sure what is happening with the insertion of those two fields. I am getting 'NULL' in the database after insertion. Please help me to find out.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using Zend. I think you must use new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()').

Comment: What is `$StartTime[$key]` and `$StartDate[$key]`? Please provide form inputs.

Comment: echo $Stime."={".$StartTime[$key]."}{".$StartDate[$key]."}";
Output:
1427704800={19:40}{03/30/2015}

Answer (score 0):

replace your line,

```
echo $i."-".$n."::user Id".$UID.."//Stime:".$Stime."//Etime:".$Etime."<br/>";
```

to,

```
echo $i."-".$n."::user Id".$UID.."//Stime:'".$Stime."'"."//Etime:'".$Etime."'"."<br/>";
```

Comment: I have tried this line and got the output as: 0-35::user Id35//Stime:'1427693580'//Etime:'1427693580'

Comment: Tried that as well. Output: 0-35::user Id35//Stime:'1427696820'//Etime:'1427696820'